# R: For() loop checking if date is between two dates in separate object

Tags: r

Thanks in advance!

I have two large datasets, both contain columns of date/time fields that are of interest.  The first (the `head()` of which is pasted below), has a single date/time field that I am interested in  – the ‘RoundDateTimeGMT’ column.  This datasheet is rather large (over 500,000 rows).  The data is specific to an individual noted by the PumaID column.

```
   PumaID   RoundDateTimeGMT
1    P01    3/3/2011 0:00
2    P01    3/3/2011 0:00
3    P01    3/3/2011 0:00
4    P01    3/3/2011 0:00
5    P01    3/3/2011 0:00
6    P01    3/3/2011 0:00
```

The second dataset has two date/time fields representing a start and end time (‘FstClstrTime’ and ‘LastClstrTime’ respectively) (below).  All times have been converted to a recognizable R format using as.POSIXct().  As above, these data are also specific to an individual noted by the PumaID column.

```
   PumaID   FstClstrTime       LastClstrTime
1    P01    8/29/2011 6:01     8/29/2011 8:01
2    P01      <NA>                  <NA>
3    P01    9/10/2011 2:00     9/12/2011 12:01
4    P01    9/9/2011 8:00      9/9/2011 14:01
5    P01    9/7/2011 8:01      9/8/2011 10:00
6    P01    9/4/2011 10:01     9/6/2011 12:01
```

My goal is to create a new binary column within the first dataset that indicates if the RoundDateTimeGMT is between the ‘FstClstrTime’ and ‘LastClstrTime’ of the second datasheet for each individual.  I only need to check if RoundDateTimeGMT is between the ‘FstClstrTime’ and ‘LastClstrTime’ if the PumaID’s of each data sheet match.  I think this can be done with a for() loop, but am open to any suggestions.  I just need to check every RoundDateTimeGMT (again there are over 500,000) to every FstClstrTime’ and ‘LastClstrTime for each individual.

With the large datasets `dput()` does not work so apologies for not attaching any data. I hope you can still offer some suggestions as how to accomplish the above goal.

Kind regards!

Comment: Please show some more effort when posting the data. [Last time you posted data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797774/trying-to-aggregate-and-average-time-series-data-collected-every-five-minutes), you got the comment: "Also [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) before posting. It makes things harder if we cannot just copy-paste or load your data".  Please don't expect someone else to both create a minimal, reproducible example _and_ answer your question. Why don't you just post the variables of interest?

Comment: Adding to @Henrik: `dput` works if you subset the data. If your data is `df` then you can subset `df[1:5,]`

Comment: And pick only the columns _relevant for your question_, e.g. `df1[sufficient-number-of-rows-not-more-not-less, c("PumaID", "RoundDateTimeGMT")]`, and similarly for the second data frame.

Comment: Good suggestions, and apologies for the poor post.  The dput() output seems way to long, given that to post a meaningful minimal there is still lots of data.  I have corrected some of your suggestions.  If there is assistance  you can offer that would be great – although I do not expect anyone to produce a minimal, reproducible an example and answer my question as suggested in an earlier comment.  
Thanks